# Why is my props updating before I update the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am trying to change an input inside a **GrandChild class** and a Bootstrap Table inside **Parent class*. An user would change the input inside **GrandChild class** then save it, so the changes are seen in the Bootstrap Table in **Parent class**; however, I am seeing this weird behavior where my props are changing before I call the .onChange (which is my save). I believe this is causing my inputs to not save or setting the state properly.

Data being passed down hierarchy: GrandParent => Parent => Child => GrandChild

It is occurring at the **Child class's *handleSave()*** function:

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.state  = {
            data:this.props.data
        }
    }


    handleChange = (name, value) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            let newState = {...prevState};
            newState.data.dataList[0][name] = value;  // data
            return newState;
        });
    };

    handleSave(){
        let dataList = this.state.data.dataList.slice();
        console.log("dataList state-dataList:", dataList);
        console.log("dataList before onChange 2:", this.props.data.dataList); //Same as dataList or this.state.data.dataList
        this.props.onChange("dataList", dataList);
        console.log("dataList onChange 3:", this.props.data.dataList); //Same as dataList or this.state.data.dataList
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <GrandChild data={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child class's *this.props.onChange*** gets sent back to the **Parent class**:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    columns = [
      {dataField: '..', text: '...' }, 
      {dataField: '..', text: '...' },  
      {dataField: '..', text: '...' }, 
      {dataField: '..', text: '...'}];


    handleChange = (name, value) => {
        this.props.onChange(name, value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable
                    hover
                    condensed={true}
                    bootstrap4={true}
                    keyField={'id'}
                    data={this.props.data.dataList}
                    columns={this.columns}
                />
                <Child data={this.props.data} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>


        );

    }

}
```

Then **Parent class's this.props.onChange*** gets sent to **GrandParent Class**:

```
export class GrandParent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: {...this.props.location.state.data}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}   

    handleChange = (name, value) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            let newState = {};
            let data = Object.assign({}, prevState.data);
            data[name] = value;
            newState.data = data;
            return newState;
        });
    };


render() {
return (
    <div>
        <Form>
        <Parent data={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </Form>
    </div>
)
}
```

This is the **GrandChild's class**:

```
export class GrandChild extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}   

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ?
        target.checked :
        target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.props.onChange(name, value);
};


render() {
return (
    <div>
        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Label>Label Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control name="labelName" value={this.props.data.[0]labelName || ""} //ignore the index for now
                              onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
    </div>
)
}
}
```

I expected that console.logs() of the dataLists to be different; however, they give the same exact object before it even runs the  **this.props.onChange("dataList", dataList);**

Potentially, the third dataList console.log might be same as the state dataList because of setState being asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main issue is that you're mutating state/props in `Child`:

```
    handleChange = (name, value) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            // {...prevState} makes a shallow copy of `prevState`
            let newState = {...prevState};
            // Next you're modifying data deep in `newState`,
            // so it's mutating data in the `dataList` array,
            // which updates the source of truth for both props and state.
            newState.data.dataList[0][name] = value;
            return newState;
        });
    };
```

One way to do this (avoiding mutation) is like this:

```
handleChange = (name, value) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: {
      ...prevState.data,
      dataList: [
        {
          ...prevState.data.dataList[0],
          [name]: value
        },
        ...prevState.data.dataList.slice(1)
      ]
    }
  }));
};
```

If that's more verbose than you'd like, you could use a library like `immutable-js`.

Another issue that could cause you bugs is copying props into state. This article gives some explanation of why that's bad: https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#dont-stop-the-data-flow-in-rendering

Basically: If you set props in state and then update state and pass props down to a child, the data you're passing down will be stale. It doesn't look like you're doing that here, but it would be easy to miss. An easy way to avoid this is to name any props you plan on setting in state `initialProp` If your prop is named `initialData`, it will be clear that from that point in the tree you should rely on the value in state rather than props.

Also, `handleChange` in `Grandparent` can be written more simply:

```
    handleChange = (name, value) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: {
          ...prevState.data,
          [name]: value
        }
      }))
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, and yes your solution was the correct one! I learned that I can't just change the data inside data. I will make sure to take some time reading article as well.

I know my question has zero as the only index, data.dataList[0], if there's more than one index, data.dataList[i], would I just need to change the slice(1)? I am seeing a problem if I am editing other indexes. Like if I try to change the first index then the second index, the second index data is copying over to first data.

But of course, I will accept your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Was able to resolve it like this with indexes:

        handleLineItemChange = (name, value) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.data = Object.assign({}, newState.data);
        newState.data.dataList = newState.data.dataList.slice();
        newState.data.dataList[i] = Object.assign({}, newState.data.dataList[i]);
        newState.data.dataList[i][name] = value;
        this.setState({ data: newState.data });
  };

Couldn't have done it without your guidance. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!